# Unity Default Animation Not Playing

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have no idea why, but often times when I create a simple default animation to an object the animation simply won't play. I'm new to Unity, but I can see no reason why this wouldn't work. Below's a screenshot of the situation. Also note that there is absolutely no code involved. The default animation is obviously called Animation, and as you can see the animation that is supposed to be played has a lot of movement going on, but the animated clip just sits there when I view the scene.

[image: Screenshot]

What on earth could be the problem? Thanks for any light you might shed on this issue.

Comment: can you add screens of the inspector infos of the animator and of the animation clip, and which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I have to ask some obvious questions since you are new to Unity. Did you set the animator for the object? Is the animation clip set to repeating? Did you set the animation clip for the default animation state?

Comment: Turns out the issue was that some God-forsaken check box was unchecked by the Animator under the inspector. I had no idea it even existed. I never would've found it if @GökhanKurt hadn't mentioned the Inspector. Post this as an answer and I'll give you the deserved credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you were missing something.
Did you set the animator for the object? Is the animation clip set to repeating? Did you set the animation clip for the default animation state?
What exactly was it?

Comment: Yes indeed, for those looking at this question in the future the problem was that the check mark next to the animation in the inspector of the game object was unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

While in the Animator window you can use the middle mouse button to move around. If you go right you can find an Exit state. Make a Transition from your animation to Exit.