# Unity build of my game wont play a default animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I have an issue with the current build and run operation on a project I'm making, where the default animation of a "scene" animator wont play, while in the editor in the same build, it does play.

This question that has a related title doesnt apply for my issue.
[Unity Default Animation Not Playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358485/unity-default-animation-not-playing)

Moreover, just after I check play on the editor to check if everything works properly, I press ctrl+b to build and run, and in-game this default animation wont play, for no apparent reason.
[image]

Everything is set properly, , the speed of the animation, the animator, etc; everything works well in the editor and inside the editor's game window, even the game's sounds run in the background. But for a reason I can't seem to find, it will not play in the build. I'm not affecting anything else than a image component to make this "scene"
animation.

Detail of the animation issue: The animation is just a sliding diagonally-rotated black image, occupying all the game screen, that gradually moves to the right until it cant be seen in the screen. For some reason, this is not playing, making the screen be pitch black.

Any ideas will help, the game is an exam.

Comment: Have you tried [Debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) this? Maybe you get an error and that's why nothing else is being executed in your built app.

Comment: Console doesnt show any errors and the game works correctly, but thanks, ima try that.

Comment: So i've set on build settings the build debugger, it builds with a result of succeded, etc, and the screen is again pitch black, having at the bottom right corner a "Development build" sign, which i attempt to click or try stuff on it, and nothing appears, and the visual studio debugger shows no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: I was using an animator override controller, in version 2019.2.17f1.
Looks like the animation override controller had unsolved bugs for that version that are not visible in the editor; or something may have got set incorrectly, despite my repeated checks on this simple animator window.

Solution: I attempted to switch back to the normal animator component just to test, and everything works perfectly as intended; the animation plays.

Any comments/critiques regarding the problem/solution are very much welcome